# invalid literal for base 10 error when converting string to integer for list in python

Tags: python

```
from statistics import mean


fo = open("numbers.txt","r") 

item = fo.readlines()

res = list(map(int, item))

print(res)
```

my numbers.txt file:

```
45 66 88
100 22 98
```

for some reason it is not possible for me to convert this list from a list of strings to integer. I need to make it an integer because I need to get the mean value of all of the integers in the file; which I was going to use the mean module from python. What am I doing wrong? My code looks clean.

Comment: You have more than one number on each line. `int()` expects just a single number.

Comment: You'll need to split your lines. There's no way for Python to convert `45 66 88` to one integer.

Comment: how do i split? Is there a split() function?

Comment: Python's readlines() method reads every line as a single string. Here 45, 66 and 88 aren't different values but it is a single string like "45 66 88". You need to split them using space (" "). 0-9 are the values with base10 while space is not a base10 value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
with open( "numbers.txt", "r") as fin :
    items = fin.read().split()

res = list(map(int, items))

print(res)
```

Two major points:

1. don't use a standalone `open()` -- you most likely will forget to `close()`
2. there's no point reading separate lines if you want to treat your file as a whole

Comment: yes it works, but im a student so i would like to learn. So on line two; you are reading the file with the read(), and then splitting it into different lines with split because python reads the text file as one line, and then you use res with map that converts the items into integers?

Comment: @johandfkalsa I'm reading the whole file, and `split()` will take care about the white spaces, that is, space, `\t`, `\n`, `\r` and maybe a few others. you may `print items` to see what I get as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your values into individual integers before trying to cast them to a list. You will also need to remove `\n`

```
from statistics import mean

fo = open("num.txt","r") 

item = fo.readlines()

res = []

for line in item: # for line of data in file
    line = line.replace('\n', '') # Remove \n
    data = line.split(' ') # Split string of numbers into individual elements in a list

    for v in data: # for each value in row
        res.append(int(v)) # append result as an integer

print(res)

[45, 66, 88, 100, 22, 98]
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` will get lines list, every item is a line str,such as `"45 66 88"`.
So you need split every line first.

```
lines = fo.readlines()
# lines is ["45 66 88", "100 22 98"]
res = []
for line in lines:
    res += map(int, line.split())
# res is [45, 66, 88, 100, 22, 98]
```

ps.Do not forget close file pointer `fo`.